# Ajustar ancho de un cardview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview, cardview

Tengo un problema a la hora de ajustar el ancho de un **cardview**. Tengo todos los *widths* a *"match_parent"* pero la lista de *cardviews* se muestra así: [image: captura de pantalla]

Los cardviews son los ítems de un *recyclerview*, este es el código del layout del recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/escanearCodigo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Escanear codigo"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Y este es el código de los ítems formados por cardviews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#81C784"
            app:cardCornerRadius="9dp"
            app:cardElevation="3dp"
            app:contentPadding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/idCodigo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/idNombre"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

La única manera que conseguí de ajustar el ancho del cardview a la pantalla es poniendo manualmente el *width* a 850px. Pero si lo añado a match parent se muestra como en la imagen.

Comment: ¿Dónde le aplicas el color verde?

Comment: aqui: `app:cardBackgroundColor="#81C784"` dentro de `<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`

Answer (score 0):

Muestra tu Adapter o sino comprueba en tu clase Adapter en el metodo onCreateViewHolder que el inflate de la vista tiene root algo similar a:

```
    var view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.tu_XML_item, parent, false)
```

esta respondida en  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503760/cardview-layout-width-match-parent-does-not-match-parent-recyclerview-width